# ¿Como exportar un documento word con imagen y guardarlo en el disco?

Tags: javascript, html

Estuve investigando la forma de exportar un documento word, y aquí le muestro el siguiente codigo:

```
<div id="source-html">
    <h1>
        <center>Artificial Intelligence</center>
    </h1>
    <h2>Overview</h2>
    <p>
        Artificial Intelligence(AI) is an emerging technology
        demonstrating machine intelligence. The sub studies like <u><i>Neural
                Networks</i>, <i>Robatics</i> or <i>Machine Learning</i></u> are
        the parts of AI. This technology is expected to be a prime part
        of the real world in all levels.

    </p>
</div>
<div class="content-footer">
    <button id="btn-export" onclick="exportHTML();">Export to
        word doc</button>
</div>

<script>
    function exportHTML(){
       var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' "+
            "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' "+
            "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>"+
            "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title></head><body>";
       var footer = "</body></html>";
       var sourceHTML = header+document.getElementById("source-html").innerHTML+footer;

       var source = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML);
       var fileDownload = document.createElement("a");
       document.body.appendChild(fileDownload);
       fileDownload.href = source;
       fileDownload.download = 'document.doc';
       fileDownload.click();
       document.body.removeChild(fileDownload);
    }
</script>
```

El problema que al colocar la imagen, no la adjunta al word. 
Y lo otro que necesito, es poder guardar el documento word en el disco o alguna ruta de mi computador.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se le agradecería.
Saludos

Fuente:
https://phppot.com/javascript/how-to-export-html-to-word-document-with-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Luego de probar varias librerias que decían solucionar el problema, adapté una para que pudieras implementar en tu ejemplo, solo recuerda tener Jquery y FileSaver en tu proyecto:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btn-export").click(function (event) {
            wordExport("documento", $("#source-html"))
        });
    });


    function wordExport(fileName, object) {
        fileName = typeof fileName !== 'undefined' ? fileName : "jQuery-Word-Export";
        var static = {
            mhtml: {
                top: "Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Base: " + location.href + "\nContent-Type: Multipart/related; boundary=\"NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\";type=\"text/html\"\n\n--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Location: " + location.href + "\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n_html_</html>",
                head: "<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n<style>\n_styles_\n</style>\n</head>\n",
                body: "<body>_body_</body>"
            }
        };
        var options = {
            maxWidth: 624
        };
        // Clone selected element before manipulating it
        var markup = object.clone();

        // Remove hidden elements from the output
        markup.each(function () {
            var self = object;
            if (self.is(':hidden'))
                self.remove();
        });

        // Embed all images using Data URLs
        var images = Array();
        var img = markup.find('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            // Calculate dimensions of output image
            var w = Math.min(img[i].width, options.maxWidth);
            var h = img[i].height * (w / img[i].width);
            // Create canvas for converting image to data URL
            var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            canvas.width = w;
            canvas.height = h;
            // Draw image to canvas
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, w, h);
            // Get data URL encoding of image
            var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            $(img[i]).attr("src", img[i].src);
            img[i].width = w;
            img[i].height = h;
            // Save encoded image to array
            images[i] = {
                type: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(":") + 1, uri.indexOf(";")),
                encoding: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(";") + 1, uri.indexOf(",")),
                location: $(img[i]).attr("src"),
                data: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(",") + 1)
            };
        }

        // Prepare bottom of mhtml file with image data
        var mhtmlBottom = "\n";
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            mhtmlBottom += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\n";
            mhtmlBottom += "Content-Location: " + images[i].location + "\n";
            mhtmlBottom += "Content-Type: " + images[i].type + "\n";
            mhtmlBottom += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " + images[i].encoding + "\n\n";
            mhtmlBottom += images[i].data + "\n\n";
        }
        mhtmlBottom += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY--";

        //TODO: load css from included stylesheet
        var styles = "";

        // Aggregate parts of the file together
        var fileContent = static.mhtml.top.replace("_html_", static.mhtml.head.replace("_styles_", styles) + static.mhtml.body.replace("_body_", markup.html())) + mhtmlBottom;

        // Create a Blob with the file contents
        var blob = new Blob([fileContent], {
            type: "application/msword;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, fileName + ".doc");
    };
</script>
```

Luego guardar a una ruta en el Equipo lo dejo para que otro usuario pueda responderte.

Fuente: https://obedalvarado.pw/blog/exportar-contenido-html-a-documento-de-word-doc-utilizando-el-plugin-jquery-word-export/

Comment: no funciona con imagen, la unica forma sería pasar la imagen a base64, pero no se como transformarla.